# hadoop not running in the multinode cluster

Tags: hadoop, classnotfoundexception

I have a  jar file "Tsp.jar" that I made myself. This same jar files executes well in single node cluster setup of hadoop. However when I run it on a cluster comprising 2 machines, a laptop and desktop it gives me an exception when the map function reach 50%. Here is the output

```
`hadoop@psycho-O:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar Tsp.jar clust-Tsp_ip1 clust_Tsp_op4
11/04/27 16:13:06 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
11/04/27 16:13:06 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
11/04/27 16:13:06 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
11/04/27 16:13:06 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201104271608_0001
11/04/27 16:13:07 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
11/04/27 16:13:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 50% reduce 0%
11/04/27 16:13:20 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201104271608_0001_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Tsp$TspReducer
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:841)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getCombinerClass(JobConf.java:853)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$CombinerRunner.create(Task.java:1100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.<init>(MapTask.java:812)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Tsp$TspReducer
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:809)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:833)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Tsp$TspReducer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:807)
    ... 7 more

11/04/27 16:13:20 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputemil-desktop
11/04/27 16:13:20 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputemil-desktop
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 bin/hadoop jar Tsp.jar clust-Tsp_ip1 clust_Tsp_op4

hadoop@psycho-O:~$ jps
4937 Jps
3976 RunJar
```

`
Alse the cluster worked fine executing the wordcount example. So I guess its the problem with the Tsp.jar file.

1) Is it necessary to have a jar file to run on a cluster?

2) Here I tried to run a jar file in the cluster which I made. But is still gives a warning that jar file is not found. Why is that?

3) What all should be taken care of when running a jar file? Like what all it must contain other than the program which I wrote? My jar file contains a a Tsp.class, Tsp$TspReducer.class and a Tsp$TspMapper.class. The terminal says it cant find Tsp$TspReducer when it is already there in the jar file.

Thankyou

EDIT

```
public class Tsp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(Tsp.class);
    conf.setJobName("Tsp");
    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    conf.setMapperClass(TspMapper.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(TspReducer.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(TspReducer.class); 
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf,new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf,new Path(args[1]));
    JobClient.runJob(conf);
    }
    public static class TspMapper extends MapReduceBase
    implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    function findCost() {
    }
    public void map(LongWritable key,Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        find adjacency matrix from the input;
        for(int i = 0; ...) {
        .....
        output.collect(new Text(string1), new Text(string2));
        }
    }
    }    
    public static class TspReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> { 
    Text t1 = new Text();
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        String a;
            a = values.next().toString();
            output.collect(key,new Text(a));
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined you reduce as static class ?

Comment: Can you post a reduced form of your code? We will likely need to see how your mapper and reducer are extending and the definitions of the overrides. As well as your Job setup code.

Comment: @Nija: I've posted a reduced form of my entire code. Thank you for taking the effort. But still I think its the problem with the jar file.Like I said this code ran fine on the single node cluster.

Comment: I've notice that it depends on how you generate you jar file, try the first option instead of the second (using eclipse). If my comment makes no sense let me know and I'll formalize it better, I'm just in  huge rush atm.

Answer (score 7):

You currently have

```
conf.setJobName("Tsp");
conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
conf.setMapperClass(TspMapper.class);
conf.setCombinerClass(TspReducer.class);
conf.setReducerClass(TspReducer.class);
```

and as the error is stating `No job jar file set` you are not setting a jar.

You will need to something similar to

```
conf.setJarByClass(Tsp.class);
```

From what I'm seeing, that should resolve the error seen here.

Answer (score 2):

```
11/04/27 16:13:06 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
```

Do what they say, when setting up your job, set the jar where the class is contained. Hadoop copies the jar into the DistributedCache (a filesystem on every node) and uses the classes out of it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue. Here is how I solved the problem(imagine your map reduce class is called A). After creating the job call:
`job.setJarByClass(A.class);`