# Hadoop C++, error running wordcount example

Tags: c++, hadoop

I am trying to run the wordcount example in c++, on Hadoop 1.0.4, on Ubuntu 12.04, but I am getting the following error:

Command:

> hadoop pipes -D hadoop.pipes.java.recordreader=true -D
>   hadoop.pipes.java.recordwriter=true -input bin/input.txt  -output
>   bin/output.txt -program bin/wordcount.

Error message:

> 13/06/14 13:50:11 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User
>   classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or
>   JobConf#setJar(String). 
>   13/06/14 13:50:11 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader:
>   Loaded the native-hadoop library 13/06/14 13:50:11 WARN
>   snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded 13/06/14 13:50:11
>   INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1 13/06/14
>   13:50:11 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201306141334_0003
>   13/06/14 13:50:12 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0% 13/06/14
>   13:50:24 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201306141334_0003_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
>   java.io.IOException   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.OutputHandler.waitForAuthentication(OutputHandler.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Application.waitForAuthentication(Application.java:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Application.(Application.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.PipesMapRunner.run(PipesMapRunner.java:71)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
>   attempt_201306141334_0003_m_000000_0: Server failed to authenticate.
>   Exiting 13/06/14 13:50:24 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201306141334_0003_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED

I didn't find any solution and i've been trying for quite a while to make it work.

I appreciate your help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found this SO question ([hadoop not running in the multinode cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803445/hadoop-not-running-in-the-multinode-cluster)) where that user got similar errors and it ended up being that they did not "Set a class" according to the top answer. This was Java however.

I found this tutorial about running the C++ wordcount example in Hadoop. Hopefully this helps you out.
http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--_Running_C%2B%2B_Programs_on_Hadoop

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it didn't help me. For the first answer ("Set a class"), i don't know if you can do that in c++ (set jar). The tutorial you've provided is actually the one I used to configure my hadoop, I've followed the same steps but it doesn't work when i try to run the example.

Comment: Are you able to run the code in that smith example? If you can run this, that could verify the validity of your Hadoop library installation. EDIT: Just saw your edit on the previous comment. Let me do some more research.

Comment: I used the exact same code as in the tutorial, I only modified the Makefile, I added -lcrypto get rid of the compilation errors.

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.3/quickstart.html#Required+Software
Seems like a lot of room for error in configuring hadoop

Comment: Also, it looks like you are getting a "server failed to authenticate" error in your message. Do you have ssh and rsync installed properly? And if you do, are the network nodes you are trying to run on properly configured to accept incoming communications?

Comment: I didn't manage to solve the problem. I followed the tutorial from apache and it worked to run the jar examples. Also it worked to run a java example. Ssh and rsync are installed, ssh localhost works without asking password and i configured the files conf/mapred-site.xml, conf/hdfs-site.xml and conf/core-site.xml as in http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/single_node_setup.html#Prepare+to+Start+the+Hadoop+Cluster.

Comment: I am all out of ideas then man. I upvoted your question. I hope it gets more attention from people who really know Hadoop. I was trying to make sure you had covered all of your basic bases when it came to troubleshooting. But it looks like your problem is not so basic. Hopefully my answer/comments help someone else troubleshoot it for you. Good luck.